# Why am I getting unexpected results comparing currency field value in Lightning Web Component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have a `currency(6,2)` field on a custom object. I'm using `@wire` to get the value from the server, which if I query using SOQL the value is `0.0`.

However, I am getting unexpected results whilst comparing the value in LWC via Javascript:

```
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value: ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value);
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === 0: ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === 0);
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == 0: ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == 0);
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == "0": ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == "0");
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === "0": ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === "0");
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == "0.0": ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == "0.0");
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == 0.0: ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value == 0.0);
```

Here is the output (note that the leading labels starting on line 2 stop showing for some reason):

```
this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value: 0
false
false
false
false
false
false
```

Here's the relevant JSON output from `_myCustomObject`:

```
"My_Currency_Field__c": {
    "displayValue": "$0.00",
    "value": 0
},
```

Why isn't any of these resulting in true? Also, any thoughts on why the labels stop showing starting on the second line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are seeing this behavior is because of [Type Coercion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Type_coercion):

> Type coercion is the automatic or implicit conversion of values from one data type to another (such as strings to numbers).

```
const value1 = '5';
const value2 = 9;
let sum = value1 + value2;
console.log(sum);
```

> In the above example, JavaScript has coerced the 9 from a number into
> a string and then concatenated the two values together, resulting in a
> string of 59. JavaScript had a choice between a string or a number and
> decided to use a string.

Now let's look at this line from your example:

```
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Current_Field__c.value === 0: ' + this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Current_Field__c.value === 0);
```

JavaScript is combining the string value of `'this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Current_Field__c.value === 0:'` with the value of `this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value` and THEN comparing the result to the value on the right. So likely you get a String on the left and comparing that to an Number on the right.

So for instance that line of your code will transform into this String: `this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === 0: 0` and this will be compared to the Number `0`.

What you can do instead is:

```
console.log('this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === 0: ');
console.log(this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually about to post the same answer. I figured out I needed to control the order of operations using parenthesis, but your method works just as well.

Comment: Something else you can do is throw a `debugger;` in your JS code and then in the console you can throw in the comparisons without any console.logs. You can directly enter `this._myCustomObject.fields.My_Currency_Field__c.value === 0` and that will give you the boolean/value you are looking for on the spot.